# Suddenly all the imported modules in my Python scripts are highlighted red in my VSCode editor

Tags: python, environment

I recently noticed that all the packages I import in all of my python files are highlighted red, and I am really bothered by it. Here is the example of the errors I get:

```
Unresolved import: goPyDev(6)
```

```
Unresolved import: pdPyDev(6)
```

I already tried reconfiguring my python environments and I checked all of the environments available, but the issue persists. Interestingly, whenever I run the file, it runs successfully, and all the modules I import are pre-installed and updated to their latest versions.

Is there anyone who faced the same issue? I believe that this might not be even related to python env, but rather to the VSCode itself. Would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: For those who faced the same issue: try restarting all the additional extensions within VSCode. I had a linter/highlighter extension which was conflicting with all of my python environments, hence the problem.